# weird beforeunload event issue

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I found a weird problem, with the `beforeunload` event.

Look at this code -

Client JavaScript:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

socket.on('connect', function() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
        socket.emit('out');
    });
});
```

Server node.js:

```
/* Basics */
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(1337, null);

io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("index.html");
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('out', function() {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});
```

If I go ahead and start the server and go to `localhost:1337` and close the tab, the server not gonna
log `disconnected`.

I figured out that if I delete the line - `io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);`
The server will log `disconnected`.

Why the server doesn't log `disconnected` in xhr-polling?

Thanks to everybody who tries to help.

Comment: Have you tried the `sync disconnect on unload` option? Described [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO).

Comment: When you delete the 'xhr-polling' line is the connection established using a WebSocket?